# Meaning of "with it way out cat"

Tags: slang

I have issues deciphering meaning of the following sentence:

> We are the Atom Cats, a gang of the most **with it way out cats** in the Commonwealth.

This sentence is from Fallout 4 game (which is not that important). The part I am struggling with is *"the most with it way out cats"*. Does that make sense to a native speaker?

Comment: I suppose that that *way out* is *[way-out](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/way-out)*, i.e., excellent, amazing, cool, and such.

Comment: I feel like mentally adding the comma helped me understand this. "We are the Atom Cats, a gang of the most with it, way out cats in the Commonwealth."

Comment: There should be two hyphens: *with-it* and *way-out* are slang terms.

Comment: This is a great example of how some of those pesky [punctuation rules](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp) help us. _"Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a compound adjective."_ If the author had written it correctly it would be easier to understand (or at least you would know to look up with-it and way-out).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a sequence of a few fairly outdated slang phrases (I get a 1970s vibe from this statement, but I was not alive in that decade to know it that is really accurate).

["With it"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/with+it/): Aware of or knowledgeable about the latest trends or developments.

["way out"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/way-out): Unconventional/excellent

["cat"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cat): Person, especially man (also potentially related to jazz musicians, if that is possibly relevant)

So the whole thing is just saying

> We're the Atom Cats, a gang of the coolest people in the Commonwealth

Comment: It's actually late 50s-early 60s slang, heavily influenced by the 'beatnik' followers of New York jazz. It would be easier to grasp if written *with-it way-out cats*.

Comment: The Atom Cats characters dress in a 1950s "greaser" style, so the slang is meant to fit in with their 50s image.

Comment: Thanks @StoneyB and recognizer - that makes sense. I don't have background knowledge of the game, and I though "cats" and "with it" seemed older than the 70s, but associated "way out" with "far out" and hippies (which I guess is 60s more than 70s, but as I said, all before my lifetime (: )

Comment: @Sarah 50s-60s was my youth; we're starting to die out. :}

Comment: I would have put "*coolest and craziest*" to capture the full connotation of *way-out*.